# Avoid line break between content and :after

Tags: html, css, css-content

I have a problem with a line break between the content of an HTML element and it's :after content.
It's a sortable table and in the head of the table is a small arrow.

You can see it in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ceuwob93/ or on this picture:

[image: Unwanted line-break after "Problem"]

Obviously I don't want that line break in front of the arrow.

```
table {
    width: 300px;
}
thead {
    background-color: #ddd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
}
th.sort-down:after {
    content: '';
    float: right;
    margin-top: 7px;
    border-width: 0 4px 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #404040 transparent;
}
```

Comment: Your table cells need fix widths. For me your code has worked without breaking the line with a cell-width of 400px and a table-width of 800px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as suggested and give your columns fixed width, or if you want a more flexible approach, you can use positioning for your :after element.

```css
 table {
        width: 300px;
    }
    thead {
        background-color: #ddd;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
    }
    .sort-down {
        padding-right: 1.5em;
        position:relative;
    }
    .sort-down:after {
        content: '';
        position:absolute;
        top:7px;
        right:5px;
        border-width: 0 4px 4px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #404040 transparent;
    }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th class="sort-down">Problem</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Some long long long Text</td>
      <td>Yes</td>
      <td>Some other long long long text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than floating the pseudo-element, try positioning it absolutely.

```css
table {
  width: 300px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
thead {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
}
.sort-down {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 12px;
}
.sort-down:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-width: 0 4px 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #404040 transparent;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th class="sort-down">Problem</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Some long long long Text</td>
      <td>Yes</td>
      <td>Some other long long long text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/ceuwob93/1/

```
position:absolute !important;
```

just change float to position absolute.

Comment: Yes, just "position absolute". No need for the `!important`.

Comment: that just for the fiddle to know that i change that value.

Comment: It was never necessary. Not even in the fiddle. I don't see *anything* in there that requires `!important`.